# Does SQLite optimize (terminate) sorting when a LIMIT clause is fulfilled?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sorting, query-optimization, android-room

I am writing some sqlite call in android using room and the most time intensive part of my process is a `select * from table order by x limit 20;` where `x` is a double and `table` can be in the order of tens of thousands of rows. My aim is to optimize this process. It is senseless for me to put an index on `x` as the tens of thousands of records are continuously reinserted every few seconds and placing an index on it would slow down the insertion process by (what I believe) would be more than the sorting process takes.

Now I know that using heap sort if you are only interested in the top 20 entries you don't actually have to go trough the entire sorting process. I know that heap sort converges to O(n ln n) so I guess stopping at the top 20 elements of a list would be O(n ln 20) or O(20 ln n) (not sure, too unqualified to do the math).

my question is if sqlite is aware of this and optimizes sorting when it encounters `LIMIT`. and if not what can I do to achieve it. could calling `MAX` 20 times potentially be faster?

Comment: I doubt that SQLite has such an optimization; it prides itself on its small code footprint.  Such an optimization would be uncommon even in more sophisticated databases.

Comment: Without an index, can such a query be optimized by *any* DB? It seems that without guaranteeing total ordering.. which is extra information an index can provide. Likewise, without an index I’d expect MAX to also be forced to read _all_ the records. So fudging a bit it’s: sorting O(n lg n) + n space vs 20 x O(n)? I would defer to a _real world / data benchmark_ and I would _also run tests when an index is used_.

Comment: Alternatively since this a single-process task, perhaps deal with the data in-memory (using a priority queue or whatnot) and use SQLite as a write-through persistence layer only. That would avoid (is such relevant? _benchmark_) the index and ordering concerns posed in the question, with a potential (needless? _benchmark_) increase in complexity.

Comment: "My aim is to optimize this process..." -- If that's the case, I would suggest you switch to a better database. SQLite is awesome, and lighweight, but it's a simple database nevertheless.

Comment: @TheImpaler That seems a bit of unnecessary evangelism. 1) It ignores problems context and domain and 2) My preferred “enterprise grade” database would fair no better theoretically in this scenario, and definitely not be a viable replacement (see #1) even if it did. — or was there a _specific_ viable recommendation following..?

Comment: first of all thanks for all the comments. i cant switch db as i am leveraging the sqlite engine already found on all android phones. @user2864740  my concern with using an index is that doing so simply defers the effort involved in the sorting process to the moment of insertion and my intuition tells me that it is even less efficient. I guess i will have to follow the benckmarking approach that you suggested

Comment: You can use `EXPLAIN` to look at the bytecode the query is compiled to which might help find an answer.